# How to use href and onclick on <a> tag simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to use href as well as onclick one after another. I am trying like this, but my javascript function is not called? Is it the right approach to do so?

```
<a href="register.php" title="" onclick="javaScript:showRegisterRules();">Register</a>

function showRegisterRules()
{
 alert("Registration Rules");
}
```

How can I achieve my functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" title="" onclick="javaScript:showRegisterRules('register.php');">Register</a>

function showRegisterRules(url)
{
 alert("Registration Rules");

 //Go to your url
 document.location.href=url;
}
```

Comment: this has no fallback for people who disable javascript or use a javascript blocker.

Answer (score 2):

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showRegisterRules()
    {
     alert("Registration Rules");
    }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="register.php" title="" onclick="showRegisterRules();">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one Question

Did you put the javascript in script tag ? Because once I did this it worked

```
<a href="register.php" title="" onclick="javaScript:showRegisterRules();">Register</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function showRegisterRules()
    {
     alert("Registration Rules");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" title="" onclick="javaScript:showRegisterRules();window.location.href='register.php'">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write a generic method here rather than one spessific to any given URL.

```
<a href="register.php" title="" onclick="showRegisterRules(this);">Register</a>

function showRegisterRules(a)
{
    alert("Registration Rules");
    document.location.href=a.href;
}
```

This way, you can reuse the same method anywhere within the site to show the alert. This allowing it to go in a script file rather than the html page

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also

```
<a href="register.php" title="" onclick="return showRegisterRules('register.php');">Register</a>

function showRegisterRules(url)
{
 alert("Registration Rules");

 return true;
}
```